# Add new record if no similar one exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

MySQL database table `mydata` has six columns, say `index`, `cola`, `colb`, `colc`, `cold`, `cole`.

Index is AUTO_INCREMENT.

I have a new set of values, `vala`, `valb`, `valc`, `vald`, `vale` respectively.

I want to insert those values into the table if and only if there is no 'similar' record, defined as being one where (`cola=vala` and `colb=valb` and `colc=valc`).  (If there is such a record, do nothing, I'm not interested in this data.)

Something like this, I think, but I can't quite get to the right syntax:

```
MERGE INTO `mydata`
USING (<something?>)
ON (insert unique key join)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (cola, colb, colc, cold, cole)
VALUES (vala,valb,valc,vald,vale)
```

Comment: Which DB are you using??

Comment: MySQL (editied post). Thanks for pointing out the omission!

Comment: I omitted to mention in my original post that there is also an AUTO_INCREMENT index field.  I suspect this is preventing the duplicates from being detected.

Comment: @Mark Smith Can you post your show create table and some example data on sqlfiddle.com? and post the link here? but it is possible to do something like this => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec664/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these columns to a composite key first.

You can use REPLACE instead of INSERT to overwrite old rows. REPLACE is the counterpart to INSERT IGNORE in the treatment of new rows that contain unique key values that duplicate old rows: The new rows are used to replace the old rows rather than being discarded. See Section 13.2.7, “REPLACE Syntax”.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

Comment: Thanks. I think the key point is creating a composite primary key, which I have done, and this solves the problem.  I can't help thinking there should be another way to do it - it might not always be appropriate to test against the primary key - but this works for me.

Comment: I think it is a good idea since the primary key is always indexed making your process more performant.

Comment: Indeed it does and in this case it is possible and the right thing to do. All good.  My point was that, in some other imaginary case, it might not be possible/desirable: I might want to add values only if no other one matching certain criteria exists, which those criteria being something other than unique the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `mydata`(cola, colb, colc, cold, cole, colf)
VALUES (vala,valb,valc,vald,vale,valf)
```

Hope this helps you.